# charts and images not shown in IE8 through SAP BusinessObjects

Tags: business-objects

**Issue:**

When Business Objects Infoview is accessed via IE8, the Images are not displayed within the Reports (red-X appears in its place). This issue is occurring when the BusinessObjects is accessed through our internal network (including when connected to VPN). The images are displayed when the reports are accessed outside our network.

**Environment Details**

```
SAP Business Objects XI 3.1 SP4 
Windows Server 2008 R2 
Tomcat 
Internet Explorer 8.
```

this is happening only on IE8.  I've tried to access the images and charts outside the network on IE8 and they display fine.

We are also seeing the following errors in the log:

(edit: unfortunately, the original poster has posted nothing about the log...)

Is there some specific setting in IE8 that I would need to tweak to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the images are not available on the internal network.  I would verify that the image can be accessed with out the Business Objects wrapper.

If you get the properties for the red X and see what the URL is that should help you pin point the root issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past and it happened to be because of an IE setting. Your VPN configuration script might be blocking the images.

Go to IE > Tools > Internet Options > Connections > LAN Settings > Uncheck "Use automatic configuration script" > Restart IE

Let us know if that worked.